# AngularJS app front-end messes up while loading

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter

When i reload the page, it shows the text with `{{` `}}` instead of processing and outputting.
How to avoid this and optimize the site to load smoothly?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use ngcloak

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

```
<div id="template1" ng-cloak>{{ 'hello' }}</div>
```

Comment: I added the directive to the div which has controller in it and bam! it's now perfect!

Thanks